# Ordenar arrays dentro de um array pela segunda posição?

Tags: javascript, array, classificação, array-multidimensional

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
[[W000817755, DIEGO HENRIQUE ALVES SANTOS, 6.00910729E8, 701620976-89, SISTEMAS DE INFORMAÇÃO, Noite, Não Matriculado, Restituição, 503.0, 23/02/2023, Não, NÃO FORMAÇÃO DE TURMA NO SEMESTRE], [W000849300, WELLERSON TOMAS DE LIMA, 6.00952314E8, 127772796-84, ENGENHARIA CIVIL, Noite, Não Matriculado, Restituição, 960.0, 27/02/2023, Não, DEVOLUÇÃO
2023.01 E 2023.02 PORQUE NÃO ABRIU TURMA], [EMAIL YURI, IURY CAUÃ DE ALMEIDA, 6.00959619E8, 129807386-38, MEDICINA VETERINÁRIA, Noite, Não Matriculado, Restituição, 490.0, 01/03/2023, Não, PAGOU BOLETO MAS NÃO FEZ MATRÍCULA]]
```

Como ordenar os arrays que estão dentro deste array pela segunda posição dos arrays dentro deles, ou seja, pelo Nome?

Tentei: `array.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);`

Não funciona, continua ordenando pela primeira posição dos arrays que é o protocolo...

Answer (score -2):

Assim funcionou:

```
 array.forEach(function(r){ 
  var tiraPoe = r[1];
  r.unshift(tiraPoe);
});
```

Peguei o array, fiz um forEach e acrescentei a segunda coluna antes da primeira nos arrays de dentro... depois é só fazer:

```
array.sort();
```

Comment: Não precisa disso. O problema é que vc está ordenando strings, então subtrair os valores (como está na pergunta) não faz sentido. Bastaria fazer `array.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))` - ou, se quiser ordem alfabética inversa, troque por `array.sort((a, b) => b[1].localeCompare(a[1]))`